# Jquery .on() loses EVENT detection after first click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a section on an intranet page that allows for a summary view of Follow-up's a employee has made in relation to customer tickets. We have added a one-click event to delete a particular record by clicking on the standard close icon at the end of each row (has class .fudel) and (value="####"). The deletion is handled by PHP via a POST event. I use the same Jquery that initiates the deletion to reload the summary DIV after sending the POST so that the summary list is current.

[image]

The problem is the event will only trigger once, after the .load() has occurred Jquery can no longer detect click events within the dynamic div. If you look at the Jquery I used it uses the .on() method which as I understand it replaced .live() and is specifically intended to deal with event detection in dynamically loaded elements.

```
$('.fudel').on("click", function() { 
    var m = $(this).attr("value"); 
    var answ = confirm("Press OK to DELETE follow-up record for: ("+ m +")");
    if (answ == true) {
        $.post("includes/phpfunctions.php", {
            fudelete: m
        });
        $("#followup").load(location.href + " #followup > *");
    } 
    else {
        $.alert('Deletion Canceled', 'User Notice');
    }
});
```

Also, in two recent question I found that a number of these event detection problems hovered around the need to add the second, third, fourth etc. etc. Jquery calls into the "Callback" of the on() event. If that ends up being an explanation for the problem here, I would ask someone to provide a good link to documentation that explains when Jquery actions need to fall **within** the callback scope vs when it can/should fall **outside** of the callback scope.

Comment: If the `load()` function is replacing the contents of the table (which includes the `.fudel` elements) you need to use a delegated event handler.

Comment: Could you please try to isolate and reproduce it in a jsfiddle?

Comment: If you look at jquery's [live()](https://api.jquery.com/live/#entry-longdesc) documentation - it shows which version of `.on()` to use that replaces `.live()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the `load()` function is replacing the contents of the table (which includes the `.fudel` elements) you need to use a delegated event handler. Try this:

```
$('#followup').on('click', '.fudel', function() { 
    var m = $(this).attr("value"); 
    var answ = confirm("Press OK to DELETE follow-up record for: ("+ m +")");
    if (answ == true) {
        $.post("includes/phpfunctions.php", {
            fudelete: m
        });
        $("#followup").load(location.href + " #followup > *");
    } 
    else {
        $.alert('Deletion Canceled', 'User Notice');
    }
});
```

Note that the `click` event is now bound to the `#followup` element and delegated to any child `.fudel` element.

Comment: Thanks @Rory i assumed since ".fudel" was previously targeted in the DOM and the load() refreshed/reloaded elements that had the ".fudel" class in them, that the event handler didn't need to be a delegated handler. Honestly im starting to think all handlers need to be delegated off of the "body" tag just to stop these headaches.

Comment: I'm afriad not - the event is bound specifically to that instance of the element, so if you remove the element and replace it - even if it has the same attributes - it won't have the event handler. You could make everything delegated from the `body` element, however this could potentially make the page very slow to respond to events, as every one would have to traverse through *every* parent element to find the `body` before it actually fired. This is the *exact* reason why `live()` was deprecated, as this is how it used to work, except it was delegated to the `document` object, not the `body`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan anecdotal evidence, but I don't experience any detectable latency by catching literally all application events at the body level (or document). Since no elements in the DOM tree below that have any handlers registered, the bubbling happens as fast as the browser internals can walk up the DOM. Even complicated pages aren't more than a couple dozen levels of nesting. I understand that it must be more latency than a "local" handler, but the difference is probably in the microseconds.

Answer (score 3):

Try delegation event, because if you make this:

```
 $('.fudel').on("click", function() {
```

It attach the event to `.fudel` if this element exists, but if not exists in the DOM loading, you can make this:

```
 $('body').on("click", ".fudel", function() {
```

By this mode you target an element that may exists in the future, but not neccesary on DOM ready.

Comment: Thanks Marco's, Rory beat ya to it :)

Comment: No problem. There's as the champions league, or a FIFO stack, fist in, first out :)